# Beanstalk: Node.js deployment - node-gyp fails due to permission denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Deployment of a Node.js application (Node 6, npm 5) to Beanstalk fails with:

> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
>   '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/heapdump/build'

though the error is not package-specific, any node-gyp call fails.

The ERROR event in the AWS Console reads:

> [Instance: i-12345] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 1 Output:
>   (TRUNCATED).../opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line
>   180, in npm_install raise e subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command
>   '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/bin/npm',
>   '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more
>   detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

and `eb-activity.log` contained the aforementioned npm error.

The application was deployed manually by uploading a .zip file that did not include `node_modules`. I.e. it was not deployed via the `eb` command-line tool.

Answer (score 232):

### Solution

The solution is to add the file `.npmrc` to the application with the content:

```
# Force npm to run node-gyp also as root, preventing permission denied errors in AWS with npm@5
unsafe-perm=true
```

(Or configuring npm so in any other way. (Though setting `npm_config_unsafe_perm=true` in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars` did not work for me.)

### Explanation

`npm install` is run by the root user but the `node-gyp` process it triggers for some packages is run by the default user `ec2-user`. This user lacks access to the `/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/` directory created by the npm install run and owned by root. (And it likely also lacks access to `/tmp/.npm` and `/tmp/.config` created by the same.) By enabling `unsafe-perm` we force npm to run node-gyp also as root, avoiding the problem.

(Personally I would prefer to run all as `ec2-user` rather than `root` but I guess that would be more involved :-))

### Credits

[unreal0 has pointed me to the solution](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/issues/108#issuecomment-220307758)

### Related questions

- [Node.js deployment fails on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk due to directory permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141255/node-js-deployment-fails-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-due-to-directory-permission)

Comment: Thank you! `unsafe-perm=true` in `.npmrc` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Great solution. This beats the various fragile .ebextensions based workarounds out there, hands down!

Comment: I can't believe how this problem has been painting the whole street with my head. You have saved me from this. For some of you that had "command not found" issue using `$ sudo npm install` on Ubuntu, try to log in as root user using `$ sudo -s` and run your normal `$ npm install` but, don't forget to add `.npmrc` to the root folder of your node project.

Comment: You are great. The worst thing about beanstalk is that the docs are so incomplete so finding a solution changing the permissions... I would rather deploy multiple ec2 instances instead. your solution is the best in my opinion, even though, as you said it feels a little bad to run it as root. I would expect AWS to handle this kind of stuff if EBS is actually a platform but until then good luck to us.

Comment: For those having a git repo connected to your application: Do not forget to commit the file. As from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) "If git is installed, EB CLI uses the git archive command to create a .zip file from the contents of the most recent git commit command." - If you dont commit, the file wont exist in your next "eb deploy"

Comment: This solution did not work for me. It's still failing

Comment: where i put .npmrc on the project or server?

Comment: You can use `--unsafe-perm` parameter when you give installation command.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had to add `npm_config_unsafe_perm=true` as an EBS environment variable to get this working for me.

Answer (score 6):

My team and I were able to get this working on an Amazon NodeJS machine by overriding some of the configuration in the script that initializes the service. This essentially overwrites the included aws node run configuration with the exact same script and a couple of extra commands. This is a file you would place under `.ebextensions`

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      #==============================================================================
      # Copyright 2013 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
      #
      # Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License"). You may not use
      # this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is
      # located at
      #
      #       http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
      #
      # or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on
      # an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, express or
      # implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions
      # and limitations under the License.
      #==============================================================================

      chmod 777 -R /tmp
      set -xe

      sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
```

Comment: I tried other config files, but this one worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i fixed with aws configuration on instance.
t2.micro => t2.small or larger one.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/1276)

Comment: This is the link only answer.

Comment: This is correct. Changing the instance size will fix this.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,
solved by setting "unsafe-perm=true" in "~/.npmrc"

Answer (score 1):

We need to do 2 things here.

First one: If you do not already have a .ebextensions folder in the root of your project, create it. Then create a file in .ebextensions named 01_fix_permissions.config.

Then secondly Enable PROXY `set -xe` and `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx`

```
files:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/49_change_permissions.sh":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user tmp/
  set -xe
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx
```

Comment: What does the PROXY stuff do?

Comment: I think it's likely that the proxy stuff isn't particular to the issue at hand, and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create & commit both a `.npmrc` file and a `.ebextensions/01-permissions.config` file to resolve this:

```
www$ cat .npmrc
# Force npm to run node-gyp also as root, preventing permission denied errors in AWS with npm@5
unsafe-perm=true
www$ cat .ebextensions/01-permissions.config 
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/49_change_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user tmp/
www$
```