# Elastic beanstalk update node.js version error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to update the node.js version in my AWS elastic beanstalk instance to the latest supported version v8.9.3 included in the latest AMI release from Amazon: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.nodejs

However when I change the version number in Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Node Version -> 8.9.3 I get the following error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/synchronize/node_modules/fibers/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.76-3.78.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/synchronize/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
ETC........
```

I have updated the instance to Configuration "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.4 running Node.js" which in the documentation says it supports V8.9.3

I have tried adding a .npmrc file to the project as described in this answer [Beanstalk: Node.js deployment - node-gyp fails due to permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001516/beanstalk-node-js-deployment-node-gyp-fails-due-to-permission-denied) and I still get the same error.

Comment: Looks like you have a permission issue

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding "unsafe-perm=true" to .npmrc file (in project root) but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Environment properties" below.

- Name: NPM_CONFIG_UNSAFE_PERM
- Value: true