# Permission denied in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-ebs

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/app/staging/node_modules/grpc/src/node' 
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("healthd") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.13.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/var/app/staging/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
```

Some searches [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001516/beanstalk-node-js-deployment-node-gyp-fails-due-to-permission-denied) not worked for.

Saying that, the issue was due to lack of permission.

How to add permission? I tried with .ebextension files. But not worked as expected.

Comment: Can you show your ` .ebextension`?

Comment: Its worked after committing the code. Why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001516/beanstalk-node-js-deployment-node-gyp-fails-due-to-permission-denied)
Its worked fine after commiting the .npmrc and .ebextensions to git.