# Elastic Beanstalk: Permission denied on scripts directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image]

This is my env status.

My error log(web.stdout.log) is

> May 28 08:02:32 ip-172-31-10-222 web: sh: /var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied

I want to release my application with AWS Elastic beanstalk.
So I tried these.

```
eb init
npm run build
eb create
```

But my env status just server. Didn’t change to OK.
accessed through the root account using SSH.

```
sudo chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
```

The above code was used to grant permission to ec2, but the status still remains on the server.
The error log remains the same.

Comment: What exactly is `node_modules/.bin/react-scripts`?

Comment: @Marcin  It is the path of the file related to the node installed by Npm

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001517/19215224